# Map the following transformation: $ w = \frac{z}{|z|} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Sketch the region onto which the circle of radius $R$ centered at the origin $(|z| = R, R>0)$ is mapped by the following transformation:
$$ w = \frac{z}{|z|} $$

I know the answer to this. But my initial instinct was to do this in terms of $u, v$

I thought this should be $$w= \frac{x+iy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
Thus $$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \ ,\ v= \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
Then take the norm of this, and I have no idea what it would look like, but "plot" this on the $u,v$ plane... I got zero credit, though my text Complex Variables and Applications has this method in section 14

Comment: What would $w$ equal if you expressed $z$ as $z=\vert z\vert(\cos\theta+i\,\sin\theta)$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Perhaps even simpler: what is $\;|w|\;$ equal to?

Comment: @DonAntonio Exactly.

Comment: I suspect you got $0$ credit because your teacher thought you did not realize that $w$ maps every $z$ onto the unit circle.